# OutOfMemoryError using MapContainer

Tags: codenameone

After my splash screen, my mainform contains a MapContainer where I show a several points. It works well on Simulator. On device however, after some seconds, the phone just hangs and the app crashes. Does it have anything to do with the way I add multiple points? I have shown the code below. I have also added my LogCat stackTrace.

```
public void addMarkers(MapContainer mc)
   {
       Vector v=  new Vector();
       try
       {
        Style s = new Style();
        s.setFgColor(0xff0000);
        s.setBgTransparency(0);
        FontImage markerImg = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_PLACE, s, 7);
        EncodedImage ei = EncodedImage.createFromImage(markerImg, false);
        List lx = (List) Storage.getInstance().readObject("CASES");
        Coord c = null;
       for(Object m: lx)
       {
           Map p= (Map) m;
           c = new Coord(Double.parseDouble(p.get("latitude").toString()), Double.parseDouble(p.get("longitude").toString()));
           v.add(c);
           mc.addMarker(ei, c, "Hi marker", "Optional long description", new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    ToastBar.showMessage("You clicked the marker", FontImage.MATERIAL_PLACE);
                }
            });
       }
       mc.fitBounds(BoundingBox.create(v));

       }catch(Exception er){er.printStackTrace();}       
   }
```

And my LogCat strackTrace below

```
01-29 00:06:24.407 21924-22089/com.jajitech.mobile.creporter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: androidmapsapi-Snapshot
    Process: com.jajitech.mobile.creporter, PID: 21924
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1831692 byte allocation with 48112 free bytes and 46KB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:975)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:946)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:913)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.a.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14366045@14.3.66 (040304-213742215):9)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bk.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14366045@14.3.66 (040304-213742215):4)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: How many markers are you adding?  They take up RAM, not too much but still. Also the marker image seems a bit too large, try 4mm instead of 7mm.

Comment: I am adding 11 markers. I have reduced the marker size to 4mm. Same error.

Comment: I am adding 11 markers. I have reduced the siz to 4mm and it seems to be fine. I had installed a wrong build initially. What then is the best practice when adding over 50 to a 100 or more markers to a MapContainer?

Comment: It should work for about 100+ markers but might fail for more the a thousand. Notice that you can pass null for the image and you would get the default image. That might further save RAM